# cake php 3.x, model join 3 table

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp, join

Im trying to join 3 tables in cake php.
I'll shorten the table I have to make it simple.

```
table_users(
    id int primary key,
    username varchar(10),
    password varchar(10),
)


table_details(
   id int primary key,
   user_id int, //fk of table_users.id
   //more fields here
)

table_ot(
       id int primary key,
       user_id int, //fk of table_users.id
       //more fields here
    )
```

I plan to join the table_details and table_ot by using there user_id.
In the model that was generated by cake bake, the table_details is joining table_users and table_ot is table_users.

But table_details is NOT joining table_ot.
This is the content of table_details and table_ot.

```
   $this->belongsTo('table_users', [
        'foreignKey' => 'user_id',
        'joinType' => 'INNER'
    ]);
```

also tried this one in the controller still does not work.

```
   $Overtime = $this->table_ot->find()->all(array('joins' => 
        array(
            'table' => 'table_table_details',
            'alias' => 'table_table_details',
            'type' => 'full',
            'foreignKey' => false,
            'conditions'=> array('table_ot.user_id = table_table_details.user_id')
        )
    ));
```

Any advise.. Help please

Comment: Looks like table_details and table_ot are not in relation..so why do you need to join them ?? And using contain is more easier here in cakephp instead of join..

Comment: @ManoharKhadka there are some fields in table_details that I need to pull from table_ot. they have the same value of user_id. in sql statement they can be joined like table_details.user_id = table_ot.user_id

Answer (score 0):

As you pointed in your question, you have already tables associations set up. So you can write your query like this:

```
$this->table_ot->find("all",[
    "contain" => [
        "table_users" => ["table_details"]
    ]
]);
```

After executing this query with, for example, toArray(), you can access your table_details record associated with table_ot like this:

```
$detailId = $results[0]->table_users->table_details->id;
```

As an alternative, I would suggest you to try joining these two tables like so:

```
//in initialize() method of your ot_table:
$this->hasOne("table_details")
    ->setForeignKey("user_id")
    ->setBindingKey("user_id");
```

All available options for each type of associations are listed here: https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/associations.html

Answer (score 0):

```
You have to add another field in table_ot to join with table_details according to cake convention. Because you have a foreign just to join with user table.

table_ot(
       id int primary key,
       user_id int, //fk of table_users.id
       details_id int, //fk of table_details.id
       //more fields here
    )
Then add this code in table of table_ot
$this->belongsTo('table_details', [
        'foreignKey' => 'details_id',
        'joinType' => 'INNER'
    ]);
```